# Javascript - cannot add dynamically button into a form

Tags: javascript

I've a little problem with functions in javascript. I have a form in which I ask to a user to enter a question and an integer (I've one label and input for the question, one label and input for the integer).

If the user have several questions to ask, I have a button which can allows to create a question.

This is the html code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="libre"></form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="q_libre.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the js file :

```
function create_question(form,nb) {

      var lbl_q=document.createElement("label");
        lbl_q.setAttribute("id","lbl_q"+nb);
        var output_q=document.createTextNode("Enter your question : ");
        lbl_q.appendChild(output_q);

        var input_q = document.createElement("input");
        input_q.setAttribute("id","input_q"+nb);

        var lbl_w = document.createElement("label");
        lbl_w.setAttribute("id","lbl_w"+nb);
        var output_w = document.createTextNode("Maximum of words for the answer : ");
        lbl_w.appendChild(output_w);

        var input_w = document.createElement("input");
        input_w.setAttribute("id","input_w"+nb);


        form.appendChild(lbl_q);
        form.appendChild(input_q);
        form.appendChild(lbl_w);
        form.appendChild(input_w);

    }



    $(document).ready(function () {

        var nb_q = 0;
        var form=document.getElementById("libre");

        var but_create = document.createElement("button");
        but_create.setAttribute("id","create_b");
        var output_c = document.createTextNode("Create exercise");
        but_create.appendChild(output_c);

        var add_question = document.createElement("button");
        var text_add = document.createTextNode("Add questions");
        add_question.setAttribute("id","add_q");
        add_question.appendChild(text_add);
        add_question.onclick = function () { create_question(form,nb_q);};

        create_question(form,nb_q++);
        form.appendChild(add_question);
        form.appendChild(but_create);

    });
```

The problem is that the creation of label and input is in a function and  when I click on the button "add question", I can see the new label and input but they immediately disappear !

I'm new in the Javascript world so someone have an idea to keep the new label and input ? Is it to have this code in a function ?

Thank's

Comment: And why do you include jQuery if you're not going to use it ?

Comment: I need to use JQuery for something after :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gs5jb/

Comment: read my answer. I think you should return false in the click event handler

Comment: add_question.onclick = function () { create_question(form,nb_q);return false;};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return false

```
add_question.onclick = function () { 
    create_question(form,nb_q); 
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside a form without any `input` element with `submit` type, click a button will submit the form. In your case, the `form` element have no `action` property, so your page will be **reload** which cause the newly inserted elements *"disappear"*.

To prevent the form submited when clicking a button, return `false` in the `onclick` event handler. Edit this line:

```
add_question.onclick = function () { create_question(form,nb_q);};
```

to:

```
add_question.onclick = function () { create_question(form,nb_q); return false;};
```

However, you can use jQuery to create new element in an easier way. Just study from its documentation.